# Radio buttons seemingly locked

Tags: html, css

Why are the radio buttons in the following not clickable? Well if I click the unchecked one it does not become checked.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Testing Pie Chart</title>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
    .clickBut {
        font-family: verdana;
        font-size: 9px;
        font-weight: bold;
        background-color: #ffa500 !important;
        border-radius: 100px;
        shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }
    
    #controlDiv {
        position: absolute;
        top: 15px;
        left: 10px;
        width: 750px;
        height: 35px;
    }

    #prodTitle {
        position: absolute;
        top: 60px;
        left: 90px;
        width: 750px;
        height: 35px;
    }
    
    #threeSquares {
        position: absolute;
        top: 70px;
        left: 10px;
        width: 70px;
        height: 250px;
    }
    
    .slice {
        font-size: 12pt;
        font-family: Verdana;
        fill: white;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    .line {
        fill: none;
        stroke-width: 3px;
    }
    
    .title {
        font-family: Verdana;
        font-size: 11px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    .yAxis text,
    .xAxis text {
        font: 7pt Verdana;
        stroke: none;
        fill: black;
    }
    
    .axis--y path,
    .axis--x path {
        display: none;
    }
    
    .axis--x line,
    .axis--y line {
        stroke: black;
        fill: none;
        stroke-width: 2px
    }
    
    .axis--y line {
        stroke-width: 1px
    }
    
    .bar:hover {
        fill: orange;
    }
    
    .d3-tip {
        line-height: 1;
        font-size: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
        color: #fff;
        border-radius: 2px;
    }
    
    .d3-tip:after {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        display: inline;
        font-size: 10px;
        width: 100%;
        line-height: 1;
        color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
        content: "\25BC";
        position: absolute;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    .d3-tip.n:after {
        margin: -1px 0 0 0;
        top: 100%;
        left: 0;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="controlDiv" style="text-align:left">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="mode" value="rev" onclick="xxx();"> 
        REV
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="mode" value="cnt"  onclick="xxx();" checked> 
        CNT
    </label>
</div>

    <div id="controlDiv"></div>
    <div id="threeSquares"></div>
    <div id="prodTitle"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d/%m/%Y").parse;


    addSquares();
    addProdTitl();



    //############# SQUARES ###################
    function getdta() {
        return {
            'label': ['N', 'P', 'B'],
            'col': ['#2bc896', '#FFA500', '#000']
        };
    };

    function squaresBasics() {
        var margin = {
                top: 35,
                right: 5,
                bottom: 5,
                left: 5
            },
            width = 70 - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = 250 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        return {
            margin: margin,
            width: width,
            height: height
        };
    }


    function addSquares() {

        var dta = getdta();

        var basics = squaresBasics();
        var margin = basics.margin,
            width = basics.width,
            height = basics.height;

        //Create SVG element
        var SQsvg = d3.select("#threeSquares")
            .append("svg")
            .attr({
                "width": width + margin.left + margin.right,
                "height": height + margin.top + margin.bottom,
                id: "squaresArea"
            });

        var SQg = SQsvg
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        SQg.selectAll("rect")
            .data(dta.label)
            .enter()
            .append("rect")
            .attr({
                x: margin.left,
                y: function(d, i) {
                    return i * 65
                },
                "width": width,
                "height": 50,
                fill: "blue"
            })
            .on("click", up);

        SQg.selectAll("text")
            .data(dta.label)
            .enter()
            .append("text")
            .text(function(d) {
                return d;
            })
            .attr({
                x: margin.left,
                y: function(d, i) {
                    return i * 65 + 20;
                },
                "font-family": "sans-serif",
                "font-size": "15px",
                fill: "white"
            })
            .on("click", up);


        function up(d, i) {
            //update bar chart when user selects a square
            var dta = getdta();
            // updateTitle(dta.label[i]);
            updateTitle(d, dta.col[i]);

        }
    }


    // ###########################################
    function prodTitlBasics() {
        var margin = {
                top: 2,
                right: 2,
                bottom: 2,
                left: 70
            },
            width = 700,
            height = 35;

        return {
            margin: margin,
            width: width,
            height: height
        };
    }

    function addProdTitl() {

        var basics = prodTitlBasics();
        var margin = basics.margin,
            width = 700 - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = basics.height;

        console.log(width)

        var svg = d3.select("#prodTitle")
            .append("svg")
            .attr({
                "width": "100%",
                "height": "60",
                x: 70
            });

        var svgG = svg
            .append("g")
            .attr({
                "transform": "translate(" + margin.left + "," + 25 + ")",
                id: "svgGxxx"
            });


        svgG.append("rect")
            .attr({
                "transform": "translate(0,2)"
            })
            .attr({
                x: 25, //margin.left,
                y: 25, //margin.top,
                width: 700, //width,
                height: 5, //20,
                fill: "#2bc896"
            })

        svgG.append("text")
            .text("XXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
            .attr({
                x: 25, //margin.left,
                y: 25, //height, //margin.top,// + 12,
                "font-family": "sans-serif",
                "font-size": "13px",
                "font-weight": "bold",
                fill: "#2bc896"
            })
    }

    function updateTitle(x, c) {
        console.log(x)

        var svg = d3.select("#svgGxxx")
        var t = svg.transition()
            .duration(1400);

        t.selectAll("text").text(x)
        .attr({
                fill: c
            })

        t.selectAll("rect")
            .attr({
                fill: c
            })
    }

    function xxx(){
        console.log("hello world")
    }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The controlDiv is placed on top of the radio buttons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two DIV elements with the same ID (controlDiv) which is not allowed.  Remove the second, empty one, which is being placed on top of the radio buttons.

```js
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d/%m/%Y").parse;


addSquares();
addProdTitl();



//############# SQUARES ###################
function getdta() {
  return {
    'label': ['N', 'P', 'B'],
    'col': ['#2bc896', '#FFA500', '#000']
  };
};

function squaresBasics() {
  var margin = {
      top: 35,
      right: 5,
      bottom: 5,
      left: 5
    },
    width = 70 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 250 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  return {
    margin: margin,
    width: width,
    height: height
  };
}


function addSquares() {

  var dta = getdta();

  var basics = squaresBasics();
  var margin = basics.margin,
    width = basics.width,
    height = basics.height;

  //Create SVG element
  var SQsvg = d3.select("#threeSquares")
    .append("svg")
    .attr({
      "width": width + margin.left + margin.right,
      "height": height + margin.top + margin.bottom,
      id: "squaresArea"
    });

  var SQg = SQsvg
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  SQg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(dta.label)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr({
      x: margin.left,
      y: function(d, i) {
        return i * 65
      },
      "width": width,
      "height": 50,
      fill: "blue"
    })
    .on("click", up);

  SQg.selectAll("text")
    .data(dta.label)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d;
    })
    .attr({
      x: margin.left,
      y: function(d, i) {
        return i * 65 + 20;
      },
      "font-family": "sans-serif",
      "font-size": "15px",
      fill: "white"
    })
    .on("click", up);


  function up(d, i) {
    //update bar chart when user selects a square
    var dta = getdta();
    // updateTitle(dta.label[i]);
    updateTitle(d, dta.col[i]);

  }
}


// ###########################################
function prodTitlBasics() {
  var margin = {
      top: 2,
      right: 2,
      bottom: 2,
      left: 70
    },
    width = 700,
    height = 35;

  return {
    margin: margin,
    width: width,
    height: height
  };
}

function addProdTitl() {

  var basics = prodTitlBasics();
  var margin = basics.margin,
    width = 700 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = basics.height;

  console.log(width)

  var svg = d3.select("#prodTitle")
    .append("svg")
    .attr({
      "width": "100%",
      "height": "60",
      x: 70
    });

  var svgG = svg
    .append("g")
    .attr({
      "transform": "translate(" + margin.left + "," + 25 + ")",
      id: "svgGxxx"
    });


  svgG.append("rect")
    .attr({
      "transform": "translate(0,2)"
    })
    .attr({
      x: 25, //margin.left,
      y: 25, //margin.top,
      width: 700, //width,
      height: 5, //20,
      fill: "#2bc896"
    })

  svgG.append("text")
    .text("XXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
    .attr({
      x: 25, //margin.left,
      y: 25, //height, //margin.top,// + 12,
      "font-family": "sans-serif",
      "font-size": "13px",
      "font-weight": "bold",
      fill: "#2bc896"
    })
}

function updateTitle(x, c) {
  console.log(x)

  var svg = d3.select("#svgGxxx")
  var t = svg.transition()
    .duration(1400);

  t.selectAll("text").text(x)
    .attr({
      fill: c
    })

  t.selectAll("rect")
    .attr({
      fill: c
    })
}

function xxx() {
  console.log("hello world")
}
```

```css
.clickBut {
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 9px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #ffa500 !important;
  border-radius: 100px;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
#controlDiv {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 750px;
  height: 35px;
}
#prodTitle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  left: 90px;
  width: 750px;
  height: 35px;
}
#threeSquares {
  position: absolute;
  top: 70px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 70px;
  height: 250px;
}
.slice {
  font-size: 12pt;
  font-family: Verdana;
  fill: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}
.title {
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.yAxis text,
.xAxis text {
  font: 7pt Verdana;
  stroke: none;
  fill: black;
}
.axis--y path,
.axis--x path {
  display: none;
}
.axis--x line,
.axis--y line {
  stroke: black;
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 2px
}
.axis--y line {
  stroke-width: 1px
}
.bar:hover {
  fill: orange;
}
.d3-tip {
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
.d3-tip:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  content: "\25BC";
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}
.d3-tip.n:after {
  margin: -1px 0 0 0;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
<div id="controlDiv" style="text-align:left">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="mode" value="rev" onclick="xxx();">REV
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="mode" value="cnt" onclick="xxx();" checked>CNT
  </label>
</div>

<div id="threeSquares"></div>
<div id="prodTitle"></div>
```

Comment: why did my question get down-voted - it seems well structured and reasonable?

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML is invalid. You have two elements with `id="controlDiv"`, which is forbidden.

The CSS is absolutely positioning them in the same spot.

The second one is covering up the first one and intercepting the clicks before they reach the radio buttons in the first one.

Comment: Friday afternoon strikes! Revenge of copy & paste

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```html
 <label>
                <input type="radio" name="group1" value="Milk">
                Milk
            </label><br/>
```

**or**

```html
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="Milk" id="rad1"><label for="rad1">Milk</label>
```